# Serialize Exception in database

Tags: java, database, serialization

I'm working on a log api which the main business object is structured like this.

```
public class Log{
    private int identifier;
    private Exception exception;
    private Severity severity; 
    private Date date;
    private String message;
}
```

Severity is an Enum
Exception is the java basic class Exception.

I wanted to store in database my logs but I'm not sure about storing a serialization of the exception in the database. Or if i should only store the stackTrace.

Wouldn't, in a log system which may create tons of lines, this fill my storage at high speed ?

If I want to also store it in a csv fill while the database is offline.
Could a serialization produces a "," which may mess with my csv column ?

---

Edit : 
As I said in comments this project is a personnal project to learn and I want to use it in my other personnal applications. But it'll be open-source, so I can't anticipate the storage size of everyone using it not more than the database system they'll use.

Comment: It depends on how much storage you have.

Comment: If you're writing a CSV file, use a library so that you don't have to worry about whether the data you are writing contains commas, newlines etc.

Comment: @4castle This project will be open-source a shipped with a web application to read the logs. So I can't anticipate the users storage's size

Comment: @AndyTurner So you say that by default it's a possibility ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as data storage size is concerned, try to look at db options like Mongo 3.2 which support wired tiger storage engine by default. This provides a default compression upto 90%. This means a 10GB log storage will be stored in the compressed form in just 1-1.5 GB space. For this you even dont need to make any change in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Log4J has been one of the most popular logging systems. It's capable of logging to several repositories including a database.

Regarding performance, it's better to use a logging system that use separate threads than main one for writing logs, as log4j does, for minimal impact in performance.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/

Comment: I'm still learning dev, so I want to work on my own system which I'll use in my personnal applications. I'm not seeking for a high perf system.

Comment: Still [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) could be a good reference for fill your backlog up. Good luck!